# Shiny Error when trying to plot a line using Plotly

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

Getting the following error when trying to plot a line using plotly. It is working fine with ggplot and I updated all the libraries. Any suggestions would be really helpful.

```
p <- plot_ly(stock_data, x= ~stock_data$X, y= ~stock_data$Shares.Traded, name 
    = "Shares Traded", type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines')
p

Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘shiny’
```

Comment: Did you try restarting your R session?

Comment: I did. I tried to run it in Rstudio and through terminal.